# html5 image is not loaded into canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a picture into HTML5 Canvas.
when i use a URL to load the image everything works fine, but if i put the image on the local drive and point to it, nothing happens.

note: when i use a regular  tag, everything works fine and the image is loaded.

here is the code:

> ```
>   var canvas = document.getElementById("rightSide");
>     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
>     var imageObj = new Image();
>     imageObj.src = "cloud.gif";
>     context.drawImage(imageObj, 650, 55, 93, 104);
> ```
>
> <
>   canvas id="rightSide"  width="800px" height="800">

thanks.

Comment: When is the code being executed? In a script tag, or onload, or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    can.width = img.width;
    can.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
img.src = 'image.jpg';
```

Comment: for some insane reason it works. Thanks. i don't understand what in your code makes the difference.

Comment: The onload closure is being called *after* the image has loaded in this code. Your code doesn't guarantee that this ordering will occur.

Answer (score 0):

A local file being loaded into canvas is treated as being from a different source and therefore "tainted". This is why it's not working for your local file, but does for a URL.